# How can I make sure my query inserts a new row?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my query:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2) VALUES('val1', 'val2')");
```

I'm trying to understand that query inserts a new row or not? How can I determine it?

---

**Note:** I'm not using `execute()` in this case.

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661863/pdo-mysql-how-to-know-if-insert-was-successful and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833499/syntax-for-if-else-statement-if-insert-was-successful-in-a-pdo-prepared-statemen

Comment: @Fred-ii- Both of them are about `execute()` function *(which returns `true` on success)*, bud as I mentioned, I don't use `execute()` function in this case. I'm using `query()`.

Comment: the principle is the same

Comment: @Fred-ii- Do you mean `query()` function also returns *true* on success?

Comment: try/catch check for errors

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from
[w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

You're looking for this: **if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)**

**Edit:**
Sorry, took wrong example as [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816093/drew) pointed out!

Below is correct snippet, it does make use of execute, as I think it should (correct me if I'm wrong!)

This link might be of more use: [pdostatement.execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
     VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
     // use exec() because no results are returned
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

and

```
<?php 
function customExecute(PDOStatement &$sth, array $params = array()) { 
    if (empty($params)) 
        return $sth->execute(); 
    return $sth->execute($params); 
} 
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean taken from an unrelated dblibrary reference?

Comment: Juan, at the bottom there is PDO. Even still, it would return a `PDOStatement`, no? Am I wrong, I might be. Please tweak your answer so I can turn my DV into an upvote my friend.

Answer (score 0):

PDO [query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) function will return a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

You can check for the [error code](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) in the PDOStatement. It should be 0 if everything was executed succesfully.
Another option, is checking to [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function result - if new row was inserted, it should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You typically perform [`execute()`](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.execute) call on a [`PDOStatement`](https://devdocs.io/php/class.pdostatement) object, returned via [`prepare()`](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.prepare) call.

Here, the return value of your `query()` call would also be `PDOStatement` object on which, you can apply your [`rowCount()`](https://devdocs.io/php/pdostatement.rowcount).

> **`PDO::query()`** returns a `PDOStatement` object, or `FALSE` on failure.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. May you please tell me what's a `PDOStatement` look like?

Comment: It looks like something ready to execute, or bind parameters into (yea).

Comment: @Drew Is that like a query? Like `INSERT INTO ...` ?

Comment: It can be, sure, just like yours.

Comment: In a properly configured application PDO::query() does not return FALSE on failure.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, I know. Which is why it was not mentioned in my answer, except for the quote where the PHP docs says so.